# Function that returns Reader to http.Response

Tags: http, go, io

This is a stripped-down version of the code I want to use for a page-specific web crawler. The idea is to have a function that gets a URL, deals with HTTP and returns a `Reader` to the response body `http.Response`:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    const url = "https://xkcd.com/"
    r, err := getPageContent(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f, err := os.Create("out.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    io.Copy(f, r)
}

func getPageContent(url string) (io.Reader, error) {
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return res.Body, nil
}
```

The response body is never closed, which is bad. Closing it inside of the `getPageContent` function won't work, of course, for `io.Copy` won't be able to read anything from a closed resource.

My question is rather of general interest than for the specific use case: How can I use functions to abstract the gathering of external resources without having to store the whole resource in a temporary buffer? Or should I better avoid such abstractions?

Comment: In the general case, you need to either hang on to the original resource (the http response), or make a copy of it. Either way, you'll have the body held in memory. Whether you want to keep the rest of the response is up to you. I would personally copy whatever information I need from the response and close it.

Comment: I don't understand your general case question, but in this case why not return a ReadCloser instead? BTW Go proverb says that always receive an interface but always return a struct.

Comment: That totally fixes my problem, thank you!

Comment: Also note that I question the existence of this "utility" function, as it doesn't help you reduce your code. Adding this function, you have to call it and check for errors, and you have to take care of closing the source. This is the same amount of code if you do it yourself (call `http.Get()`, check for errors and close the source). Of course you may add other functionality into `getPageContent()` which could make it useful.

Comment: @icza Your point is valid for the code as above, but as you also mentioned, the function actually might do more things than in this stripped-down example, proper logging being one of the tasks to be done.

Comment: @icza Checking the status code is another point I forgot about. So the `getPageCount` function is much bigger in a real world application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by the user *leaf bebop* in the comment section, the function `getPageCount` should return an `io.ReadCloser` instead of just an `io.Reader`:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    const url = "https://xkcd.com/"
    r, err := getPageContent(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer r.Close()
    f, err := os.Create("out.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    io.Copy(f, r)
}

func getPageContent(url string) (io.ReadCloser, error) {
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return res.Body, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is you can directly return the response and close it in main function. In general you can put checks on response StatusCode etc. if new requirements come. Here is the updated code:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    const url = "https://xkcd.com/"
    r, err := getPageContent(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    if r.StatusCode !=http.StatusOK{
    //some operations
    }
    f, err := os.Create("out.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    io.Copy(f, r.Body)
}

func getPageContent(url string) (*http.Response, error) {
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return res, nil
}
```

Comment: That works technically, however I'd rather have a general interface, so that I could also consume Readers from different sources later on.

Comment: @PatrickBucher. You can make it more general by changing the return types of `getPageContent` to `(io.ReadCloser, error)`.

Comment: @md2perpe Exactly as the previous answer does.

Comment: yeah can do that , but if for generic purpose want to do any checks on StatusCode would have to handle it in getPageContent function only .

Comment: @negiYogi Yes, the status code has to be checked inside `getPageCount`. This was omitted for the sake of shortness and simplicity in the code example.